# Setting up a UPnP media server on a Mac

Tags: macos, mac, ps3, upnp

I've successfully gotten my Windows computers sharing music with my PS3 using Windows Media, and I've been able to do the same thing on my Linux computer, using MediaTomb. But I can't find a decent UPnP media server for the Mac. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ps3 Media Server](http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/)

It is written in java, and will work on any OS.  You will probably need the matroska codec pack, which is also easily obtanable, because it transcodes the video on the fly to ps3 acceptable formats.  Works the same as any network fileshare program.  You add the stuff you want to share, start up the server component, and it will do the rest.  All the way from a happy little screen that tells you whether or not it can see your ps3, to advanced settings for transcoding on the fly.

Answer (score 4):

There are several choices :

- Free ones :

  1. [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) ([wiki page](http://xbmc.org/wiki/?title=Upnp))
  2. [Kinsky](http://oss.linn.co.uk/trac/wiki/Kinsky)
  3. [Plex](http://www.plexapp.com/)
  4. [uShare](http://ushare.geexbox.org/) (easier to install with [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/))
- Paid ones :

  1. [EyeConnect](http://www.elgato.com/elgato/na/mainmenu/products/software/EyeConnect.en.html)
  2. [PlayBack](http://yazsoft.com/products/playback/)
  3. [SongBook](http://bookshelfapps.com/songbookmac.php)

If you don't mind paying for a software, PlayBack seems the right choice for your need.

Comment: ushare and plex (xbmc fork) are also free and work pretty well.  (not tested with the ps3 specifically)

Comment: True. I forgot them.